# Java: Comparing String

Tags: java, string, loops

I am trying to compare two Strings based on which the boolean dontuse will be set. For practice I have set string as static but they may vary (Please dont ask how I get these Strings it a whole big beast in itself).
What I am trying to do is, check if String 'allofmycode' has any element more then 'codeChoosen' then 'dontuse' is false. But if both of the string are equal then its is false or if the string has same element written several times then also false.

So, for

(1) it will be false as it contains AB & CD which are extra.

(2) will be true as it has the same element but is duplicate.
I hope it make sense, any suggestions or help? Thanks

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    boolean dontuse = false;

    String codeChoosen = "EX,ZX";
    String allofmycode = "EX,AB,CD,EX";    //(1)    dontuse=false
    //String allofmycode = "EX,EX,ZX";        //(2)  dontuse =true

    List<String> mycodeChoosen = Arrays.asList(codeChoosen.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
    System.out.println("Selected : \t " + mycodeChoosen);

    List<String> allofmyresult = Arrays.asList(allofmycode.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
    System.out.println("All : \t" + allofmyresult);

    if (mycodeChoosen.equals(allofmyresult)) {
        dontuse = true;
    } else {
        for (int i = 0; i < mycodeChoosen.size(); i++) {
            if (allofmyresult.contains(mycodeChoosen.get(i))) {
                System.out.println(mycodeChoosen.get(i));
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("\n[DONT USE IS] : \t " + dontuse);

}
```

For example in basic english, If you have Apple, Orange and Banana; and I say people with Apple and Orange are not coming to my party. But you also have Banana so you are allowed to come to the party. But if you had two Apples or Apple and Banana then you are not allowed. I hope it make sense.

Comment: I've read the question several times, but it's still not making much sense to me. It's very unclear what the *actual* result of your current code is vs the *expected* result, why the expected result should be that way, and what you've done to diagnose the issue.

Comment: I hope it make sense now. If you have Apple, Orange and Banana; and I say people with Apple and Orange are not coming to my party but you have Banana so you can come to the party. But if you had two Apples or apple and banana then you are not allowed. I hope it make sense.

Comment: What if you have two apples, an orange and a banana?

Comment: You still haven't explained what the current output is compared with the expected output, or what you've done to diagnose the issue. When you step through the code line by line in the debugger, where does it disagree with your expectations?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dontuse = !allofmyresult.stream().anyMatch(str -> !mycodeChoosen.contains(str));
```

Comment: Small and Fast. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

As the problem seems to require only a view as **sets**, do:

```
static Set<String> codes(String list) {
    Set<String> set = new HashSet<>();
    Collections.addAll(set, list.split("\\s*,\\s*"));
    return set;
}

String codeChoosen = "EX,ZX";
String allofmycode = "EX,AB,CD,EX";    //(1)    dontuse=false

Set<String> choosen = codes(codeChoosen);
Set<String> all = codes(allofmycode);
boolean dontuse = choosen.equals(all);
// all.containsAll(choosen)
```

The original code probably was meant to do:

```
if (mycodeChoosen.equals(allofmyresult)) {
    dontuse = true;
} else {
    dontuse = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < mycodeChoosen.size(); i++) {
        if (allofmyresult.contains(mycodeChoosen.get(i))) {
            dontuse = false;
            break;
        }
    }
}
```